# Autocomplete From JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to display an auto complete text field using http://easyautocomplete.com.

It works great using their demo.

Their json is displayed like this

```
[ 
  {"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"}, 
  {"name": "Aland Islands", "code": "AX"}, 
  {"name": "Albania", "code": "AL"}, 
  {"name": "Algeria", "code": "DZ"}, 
  {"name": "American Samoa", "code": "AS"}, 
  ...
 ]
```

Where as my code is displayed like

```
[
  {
    "event": {
      "id": "28139949",
      "name": "Comp (FRA) 6th Mar",
      "countryCode": "FR",
      "timezone": "CET",
      "venue": "Compiegne",
      "openDate": "2017-03-06T12:15:00.000Z"
    },
    "marketCount": 5
  },
  {
    "event": {
      "id": "28139948",
      "name": "Yarm (FC) 6th Mar",
      "countryCode": "GB",
      "timezone": "Europe\/London",
      "venue": "Yarmouth",
      "openDate": "2017-03-06T18:33:00.000Z"
    },
    "marketCount": 11
  },
  ...
]
```

The demo code for the one that works above is as follows:

```
var options = {
    url: "resources/countries.json",

    getValue: "name",

    list: {
        match: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }
};
```

I know the problem is because my 'name' field is within 'event' fields, but I don't know how to target that.

Any advice?

Comment: Can you try this: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ Follow the steps give source: availableTags = this contains the values to autocomplete... You an use this url to check json data : [JSON VIEWER](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your data object through a map call:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "event": {
      "id": "28139949",
      "name": "Comp (FRA) 6th Mar",
      "countryCode": "FR",
      "timezone": "CET",
      "venue": "Compiegne",
      "openDate": "2017-03-06T12:15:00.000Z"
    },
    "marketCount": 5
  },
  {
    "event": {
      "id": "28139948",
      "name": "Yarm (FC) 6th Mar",
      "countryCode": "GB",
      "timezone": "Europe\/London",
      "venue": "Yarmouth",
      "openDate": "2017-03-06T18:33:00.000Z"
    },
    "marketCount": 11
  }
];

const newData = data.map(curr => {
  return {
     name: curr.event.name,
     code: curr.event.countryCode
  };
});

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd of never have found this solution!